# Is there a function to search multiple columns at once for a value, then returning the row which contains the matching value

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a","b","c","d"), m1 = c(16.0,45.0,32.0,18.0), m2 = c(17.0,46.0,33.0,19.0))
```

df

```
   name m1 m2
 1    a 16 17
 2    b 45 46
 3    c 32 33
 4    d 18 19
```

I am wondering how could I search this data frame given an input value (say 17.0) and retrieve the following output?:

```
name m1 m2
1    a 16 17
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search in all the columns we can use `rowSums`.

```
df[rowSums(df == 17, na.rm = TRUE), ]

#  name m1 m2
#1    a 16 17
```

Or using `filter_all` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. == 17))
```

Comment: How could I modify this to search over a range, say between 15 and 30? I tried using the following and it did not work: `df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. >15 & <30))`

Comment: @RylandGiebelhaus `df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. > 15 & . < 30))` or `df[rowSums(df > 15 & df < 30) > 0, ]`

Comment: I get the following error `In Ops.factor(left, right) : '>' not meaningful for factors` when I use this on my dataset.

Comment: @RylandGiebelhaus run `df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)` first and then try the above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option

```
df[which(df==17,arr.ind = TRUE)[,"row"],]
```

which gives

```
  name m1 m2
1    a 16 17
```

Comment: If I wanted to have this as a statement to search over a range, say 15 to 30, how would this be possible? I tried this but it did not work: `df[which(df > 15 & df < 30, arr.ind = TRUE) [,"row"],]`

Comment: @RylandGiebelhaus Do you mean both `m1` and `m2` should be in the interval between 15 and 30?

Comment: m1 or m2 between that interval.

Comment: @RylandGiebelhaus How about `df[unique(which(df > 15 & df < 30, arr.ind = TRUE) [,"row"]),]`

Comment: I get the following error `In Ops.factor(left, right) : '>' not meaningful for factors` when I use this on my dataset.

Comment: @RylandGiebelhaus You had that error since you used `factor` type in `df`. You can use `df <- type.convert(df,as.is = TRUE)` first